# how to architecture Spring Boot Microservice

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have an architectural question about an application I want to build. The Application will have Angular as frontend and Backend Spring Boot generated with jhipster.

I will have a microservice called manufacturer where I have the following entities:
seller
material
products.
material has an many to many relationship with seller and the owner is material. and product with material many to many and is the owner.

my question is
One material can have multiple sellers thus multiple prices. Does it make more sense to put the price field inside material or inside seller? I am not an DB expert but my guts tells me to put it inside material because it makes more logical sense from everyday use. Could someone maybe give me an advice is that ok if I put it inside material or does it make more sense to put it inside seller entity?

Answer (score 1):

Think practically being a seller. Multiple seller buy dough but have a varying a pizza prices. You might have seen online shopping websites have different prices for different sellers.

I don't know what you mean by `material` & `product` , but if I get it right, by `material` you mean raw-material for making product.

A `seller` would be linked with `material` in a `one-to-many` and with `product` in a `many-to-many` relationship.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the reason why I had put a seller to a material (like you said raw material like wood, screws etc) with many to many was because one Seller can sell different kind of materials and materials can be bought buy different kind of sellers. That was the reason why I had a many to many relationship. Products is also many to many with materials because one product is produced through different kind of materials and materials can be used with different products. Product entity are things I am producing myself. I hope I could give you a bit of an insight for my usecase